# Unable to retrieve output data from database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using the following PHP code to retrieve the shop information fields from the database but Im getting the error shown below when I run the PHP.

```
<?php
include ('database.php');


$locLat ;
$locLng ;
$shopName;
$shopContact;

$sql = "SELECT s_iD, s_name,s_contNo,s_lat,s_long from tbl_shop";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$arrayResult = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($arrayResult,array("id"=>$row['s_iD'],"shopName"=>$row['s_name'],"shopContact"=>$row['s_contNo'],"latitude"=>$row['s_lat'],
        "longitude"=>$row['s_long']));
}

echo json_encode (array('result'=> $result));


mysqli_close($con);
```

But the output is always :

> {"result":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}

Comment: Your array is called `$arrayResult` but you use `$result` when generating json

Comment: Also it is very unclearn where `current_field` and so on comes from

Comment: You should use mysqli_fetch_row instead of mysqli_fetch_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your updated code should be :

```
<?php
include ('database.php');


$locLat ;
$locLng ;
$shopName;
$shopContact;

$sql = "SELECT s_iD, s_name,s_contNo,s_lat,s_long from tbl_shop";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$arrayResult = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($arrayResult,array("id"=>$row['s_iD'],"shopName"=>$row['s_name'],"shopContact"=>$row['s_contNo'],"latitude"=>$row['s_lat'],
        "longitude"=>$row['s_long']));
}

echo json_encode (array('result'=> $arrayResult));  // <-- changed from $result


mysqli_close($con);
```